# Simulate a bank balance withdraw behavior with lambda

Tags: scheme, sicp

I am reading [3.1  Assignment and Local State of SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-20.html)

```
(define balance 100)
(define (withdraw amount)
  (if (>= balance amount)
      (begin (set! balance (- balance amount))
             balance) ;
      "Insufficient funds"))
;Value: balance

1 ]=> 
;Value: withdraw
1 ]=> (withdraw 50)
;Value: 50
1 ]=> (withdraw 30)
;Value: 20
```

This solution presents a problem with exposure `balance` state, as a solution, introduce local variable

```
(define new-withdraw
  (let ((balance 100))
    (lambda (amount) ;;
      (if (>= balance amount)
          (begin (set! balance (- balance amount))
                 balance)
          "Insufficient funds"))))

> (new-withdraw 40)
;Value: 60
```

`lambda`is introduced as well, even thought it could be rephrased as

```
(define (new-withdraw-2 amount)
  (let ((balance 100))
      (if (>= balance amount)
          (begin (set! balance (- balance amount))
                 balance)
          "Insufficient funds")))

;Value: new-withdraw-2
8 error> (new-withdraw-2 30)
;Value: 70
```

I assumed that applying  `lambda` here seems not necessary. What I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third function is very different from the second one, since in it every time you make a withdraw you compute as result value `100 - amount` (the parameter of the function), while in the second one there is an initial balance, 100, and each time that you make a withdraw, it is detracted from the *current* balance.

```
(define new-withdraw
  (let ((balance 100))
    (lambda (amount) ;;
      (if (>= balance amount)
          (begin (set! balance (- balance amount))
                 balance)
          "Insufficient funds"))))

> (new-withdraw 40)
;Value: 60

> (new-withdraw 30)
;Value: 30           ; equal to 60 - 30


(define (new-withdraw-2 amount)
  (let ((balance 100))
      (if (>= balance amount)
          (begin (set! balance (- balance amount))
                 balance)
          "Insufficient funds")))

> (new-withdraw-2 40)
;Value: 60

>(new-withdraw-2 30)
;Value: 70   ; equal to 100 - 30
```

So, `new-withdraw-2` does not model a bank account, and the function is just an elaborate way of defining `f (x) = 100 - x`.

Why these two functions differ so much, even if they seems similar at a superficial glance?

The difference is given by the semantics of the `let`: in the first case, in `new-withdraw` the `let` introduces a new variable `balance`, which establishes a new “environment”, and then return a new function (the inner `lambda`), for which the variable `balance` is external. So the returned function, each time that it is called, accesses the *same* variable and decreases its value. The next time it will be called, it will found, through the *same* variable, the value decreased in the previous call.
Objects such as the inner function are called “closures”, as the function and is external environment are strictly connected, with the environment forming a state “hidden” in the function, and persistent between the different calls of the function.

In the second case, instead, the `let` is inside the function `new-withdraw-2`: this means that each time the function is called, a *new* variable `balance` is defined, which establishes a new environment, local to the function, the variabile is initialized to 100, and then it is decreased (with `set!`). But when the function is terminated, returning the new balance, the local environment of the function is lost, and the next time the function will be called a new environment will be established again, with the variabile `balance` initialized again to 100.